# Looking for the Kernel, Basis, Range, and Dimension

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

$$
L: \mathbb{R}^4 → \mathbb{R}^4 
$$
defined by
$$
L \begin{pmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\z\\w
\end{bmatrix}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&1&3\\
2&1&-1&2\\
1&0&0&-1\\
4&1&-1&0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\z\\w
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I'm interested in looking for its kernel `Ker(L)`, find a basis for `Ker(L)` and the dimension of `Ker(L)`. Same as for its range, `range(L)` and its dimension `range(L)`.

I'm not really confident with my answer so I'm asking so that I could verify if my solution is correct.

What I did is equate the matrix above to a zero matrix.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&1&3\\
2&1&-1&2\\
1&0&0&-1\\
4&1&-1&0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\z\\w
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}
\Rightarrow
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
  1&2&1&3&0\\
2&1&-1&2&0\\
1&0&0&-1&0\\
4&1&-1&0&0
\end{array}
\right]
$$
Then I looked for its `RREF` and the result is
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
  1&0&0&-1&0\\
0&1&0&\frac{8}{3}&0\\
0&0&1&\frac{-4}{3}&0\\
0&0&0&0&0
\end{array}
\right]
$$
and decided the following:
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
x = r\\
y = \frac{8}{3}r\\
z = \frac{-4}{3}r\\
w = r \end{bmatrix}
\Rightarrow r
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
\frac{8}{3}\\
\frac{-4}{3}\\
1 \end{bmatrix}
\Rightarrow \ker(L)
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
\frac{8}{3}\\
\frac{-4}{3}\\
1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
And from there I'm not sure if I did right, and I'm confused on where next I should go in finding the rest of the problem.

I apologize if its a stupid question.

Comment: Don't exist stupid question, what I suggest you is to begin with the Kernel-Range fomula to gather some conclusions about the dimension, i.e $dim V = dim Ker(L) + dim Im(L)$

Comment: I mean there are, but this is definitely not one of them. You put in the research, and even tex'd up all of your work as a new user.

Comment: @Lemsic You could add your final solution to your question and delete the comments given to the answer. Bye

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the method you are using the key point is that row operations preserve the solution for the linear system of equations. For the solution you are almost right, $Ker(L)$ has dimension one but for its basis you have a wrong sign for $\frac83$ and $-\frac43$, that is

$$r
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
\color{red}{-\frac{8}{3}}\\
\color{red}{\frac{4}{3}}\\
1 \end{bmatrix}$$

From the REEF we also know that the image/range has dimension $3$ and we can take the first three columns (or any other triple) of the original matrix as its basis.

Comment: can I rewrite it as: 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
3\\
-8\\
4\\
3\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$ ?

Comment: Yes of course any not zero multiple is fine as basis for Ker(L).

Comment: Oh I see, I think I got it. But what's the difference of Ker(L) and the Basis for Ker(L)? and do I include `r`?

$$
\ker(L) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
3\\
-8\\
4\\
3 \end{bmatrix}
dim\ \ker(L) = 1
$$

Comment: Ker(L) is the subspace, that is a line in this case, the basis is a set of independent vectors which span Ker(L), that is a direction vector in this case. Refer to the basic definitions.

Comment: So let me get this right. I apologize again, I find it difficult to learn in online classes.
$$
\ker(L)=\begin{Bmatrix} r\begin{bmatrix}
3\\
-8\\
4\\
3 \end{bmatrix}\end{Bmatrix}
$$
$$
basis \  for \ \ker(L) = \begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
3\\-8\\4\\3 \end{bmatrix}
\end{Bmatrix}
dim\ \ker(L) = 1
$$
$$
range(L) = \begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
1\\2\\1\\4\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 2\\1\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1\\-1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}
 \end{Bmatrix}
dim \ Range(L) = 3 \\
$$
$$
dim \ Range(L) + dim\ \ker(L) \ = \ dim \ V \\
1 \ + \ 3 = 4 \\
4 = 4
$$

Comment: @Lemsic We have that basis for $range(L) $is  $\begin{Bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}  1\\2\\1\\4\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 2\\1\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1\\-1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}  \end{Bmatrix} $ that is $range(L)=span \begin{Bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}  1\\2\\1\\4\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 2\\1\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1\\-1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}  \end{Bmatrix} $.